# Dushanbe to Bishkek overland - options?

Tags: overland, tajikistan, kyrgyzstan, dushanbe, bishkek

So after having to dash back to Dushanbe for some emergency medical supplies, I'm now short on time - and won't fit in the Pamirs this trip...but I'll HAVE to come back :)

Anyway, I now need to get to Bishkek.  I have a valid Tajikistan and Kyrgyzstan visa.  I'm on a New Zealand passport.  I'd really like to go overland rather than flying, despite the pain of the roads ;)

Is there a train option that I can do - I gather it's possible via Uzbekistan but I may have to get a transit visa for that...and failing this, what's the shortest route by car, and which border would be open into Kyrgyzstan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there aren't many local trains from Dushanbe. [One of them](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=194d8c4a) goes to the [Konibodom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konibodom), but it doesn't got very straight, and just once a week (and sometimes it doesn't go at all).
So all I can suggest instead of M41 (Pamirs highway) is to go via A372 to [Osh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osh), and from there take a car or bus to Bishkek.
But I can't get any news from this region to define if there any troubles or not.